# A working link for Qt 64 bit for linux

Tags: linux, qt, ubuntu

I'm trying to get Qt 64bit for Linux. I have gone to this link http://www.qt.io/download-open-source/#section-2  to get the offline package because that is what I prefer and when IO click on the Qt 64bit link it opens a page that says this "Not Found

The requested URL /official_releases/qt/5.5/5.5.0/qt-opensource-linux-x64-5.5.0.run was not found on this server.
Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS) Server at download.qt.io Port 80"

Please can anyone help me with another link. An actual Qt 64bit link or is there another solution to this.

Answer (score 1):

The link on the page is wrong, use

http://download.qt.io/official_releases/qt/5.5/5.5.0/qt-opensource-linux-x64-5.5.0-2.run